# Tempfile to new folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two buttons **Done** and  **Submit** so when I click done I should be returned with a temp name but when I click submit then the file is moved
I am able to retrieve the temp path but the file does not move

```
$tmp_dir_ //C:/Users/userone/AppData/Local/Temp/douC9AC.tmp
$fileDestination;//C:\xampp\htdocs\work\website/wp-content/uploads/files/doucment 2_ABC2519141_128.pdf
move_uploaded_file(tmp_dir_ ,fileDestination);
```

but the file doesn't get moved
when the move upload file is called what am i doing wrong

Comment: `move_uploaded_file(tmp_dir_ ,fileDestination);` .. the variables are missing `$`

Answer (score 0):

php variable starts with`$`

Therefore, replace:

```
move_uploaded_file(tmp_dir_ ,fileDestination);
```

with the following:

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir_ ,$fileDestination);
```